# How to Method#getAnnotatedParameterTypes() in spring proxied class

Tags: spring-boot, reflection, proxy-classes

I'm using spring-boot 2+ and created some custom annotation;

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation{
}
```

When doing:

```
final AnnotatedType[] annotatedTypes = mostSpecificMethod.getAnnotatedParameterTypes();

//this will get the original class
//final Class<?> clazz = AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(bean);

Class<?> annotatedMappedClass = null;
for (AnnotatedType annotatedType : annotatedTypes) {
    if (annotatedType.isAnnotationPresent(MyCustomAnnotation.class)) {
        annotatedMappedClass = TypeFactory.rawClass(annotatedType.getType());
    }
}
```

it works when bean is not a proxy but when I add the @Transactional annotation it becomes a proxy and stops working. What is the Spring Util to find in the target class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood you'll need the bean. Using:

```
Method invocableMethod = AopUtils.selectInvocableMethod(mostSpecificMethod, bean.getClass());
```

seems to work.

Also a more complex one:

```
    Method method = mostSpecificMethod;
    if (AopUtils.isAopProxy(bean)) {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(bean);
            method = clazz.getMethod(mostSpecificMethod.getName(), mostSpecificMethod.getParameterTypes());
        }
        catch (SecurityException ex) {
            ReflectionUtils.handleReflectionException(ex);
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("...", ex);
        }
    }
```